# How to create vector in R with every combination of values in a specified format?

Tags: r

I am trying to use R to create a vector with every permutation of characters listed in the following vectors in a specified format.

```
a <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")
b <- c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")
c <- c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","J","K","L","M","N","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z")
```

With the above vectors, I would like to create a new vector with every permutation of those variables in the following format:

```
a
ac
acc
abcc
abbcc
```

The result should include values such as the following:

```
c("1","1A","348BE")
```

I initially tried using nested while and for loops, but this resulted in a big mess of code that didn't work correctly.

I recognize this will be a very large vector, so maybe this isn't the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a kludged together function to produce what you are looking for

```
library(dplyr)

item1 <- as.character(1:9)
item2 <- as.character(0:9)
item3 <- c(item2, LETTERS)



fn <- function(x){

    switch(x,
       a = {
         item1
       },
       ac = {
         expand.grid(item1, item3) %>% 
           transmute(val = paste0(Var1, Var2)) %>% 
           .$val
       },
       acc = {
         expand.grid(item1, item3, item3) %>% 
           transmute(val = paste0(Var1, Var2, Var3)) %>%
           .$val
       },
       abcc = {
         expand.grid(item1, item2, item3, item3) %>% 
           transmute(val = paste0(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4)) %>% 
           .$val
       },
       abbcc = {
         expand.grid(item1, item2, item2, item3, item3) %>% 
           transmute(val = paste0(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5)) %>% 
           .$val
       },
       stop("Doing it wrong!")
    )

}

c(fn('a'), fn('ac'), fn('acc'), fn('abcc'), fn('abbcc'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly a more elegant way to get all the formats at once, but you might do something like this for each format and then combine the results:

```
library(tidyverse)
abbcc <- crossing(a, b, b, c, c) %>% 
  unite("combinations", sep = "")

abbcc
# A tibble: 1,040,400 x 1
   combinations
   <chr>       
 1 10000       
 2 10001       
 3 10002       
 4 10003       
 5 10004       
 6 10005       
 7 10006       
 8 10007       
 9 10008       
10 10009
```